# Rails form structure for accepting Primary and Secondary email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to have a 'contact person' form that allows a user to enter their Personal and Work email at the same time.
I can imagine two ways of doing this but am not sure they're optimal and may be missing a Rails way of doing so:

1. Have the nested form create the email model twice, but add a flag for :position to identify them. (Hidden field to do so?)
2. Set up a delegate that maps :personal_email and :work_email to the Email model such that the model handles them separately.
3. Something else?

Currently I have emails set up like this:

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, ...

  has_many :emails
  #delegate :personal_email, :to => :email, :allow_nil => true
end
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :owner_id, :owner_klass, :position, :verified, :email_type
  belongs_to :individual

  # WIP Returns 'primary' email for a user
  def personal_email
  end
end
```

Comment: This doc shows the nested hash approach, if that's correct, has anyone seen this implemented with HAML?
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/form_helpers.html

Comment: Why can't you add two columns(primary_email, secondary_email) to individuals table? (if you are not using polymorphic association).

Comment: There will be an option for more than 2 emails on the Individual, and other models will have an email(s) and a similar form as well. 
Adding extra columns is trivial, I simplified the question to make it easier to grok. How to create multiple instances of a 'sub' model is the question.